# bash prompt not wrapping as expected

Tags: bash, prompt

Here it is:

Captures git branch for prompt:

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\W\[\033[0;31m\]\$(parse_git_branch)⚡️\[\033[0;39m\] "
```

It is not wrapping lines in my terminal correctly (it runs over the current line when it is supposed to wrap to the next line) and it also inserts a random alpha character (that cannot be deleted) at the beginning of my prompt (yet, this has no effect of commands I am trying to execute).

Comment: You should use single quotes instead of double quotes in `PS1='...'`.

Comment: @Mikel That doesn't matter.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Check your terminal emulator encoding, for that `⚡️` character. And why do you export your PS1?

Comment: @Arthur2e5 It requires less escaping, e.g. for `\$(parse_git_branch)` you can just write `$(parse_git_branch)`.  But you're right that the `\[` and `\]` are getting escaped correctly even inside double quotes, which is the part I was worried about.

Comment: Well, this is interesting... after I simply deleted my emoji - it starts working again... so that means my terminal doesn't like the encoding all of a sudden then???

Comment: For your reference, on my computer 26A1 FE0F displays like a 1-en glyph. I think you should use the 'text' variant, or use a monospace font that knows to override emojis. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26a1/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me and you MUST have the emoji in your prompt, this fixed the line wrap problem for me:

```
PS1="\[⚡️\]"
```

Essentially, this makes the lightning bolt not be counted in the prompts length, better explained [in this askubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111840/ps1-problem-messing-up-cli).

Comment: Won't this cause bash to go from counting too much to counting 1 less than necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, not wrapping lines. However, the green leaf emoji appears in my vim like this:

```
�~_~M~C
```

Instead of using [ ] to escape the whole sequence, I left the first one out:

```
�\[~_~M~C \]
```

Now, wrapping works and column count is also correct.

Comment: This worked perfectly on Windows Terminals but not on Macs. (added to .bashrc)

Answer (score 0):

@Arthur2e5 -- you pretty much figured it out! It was that lightning bolt emoji! For some odd reason, I can use other emoji's, but NOT the lightning bolt... weird - I know. Thank you for helping me diagnose the problem though... it's been bugging me for about a month now! LoL!