# Unicode character in PS1 makes wrapping behave weirdly (not a duplicate)

Tags: bash, prompt, unicode

I wanted to put the Unicode character Δ into `PS1`, but when I did, when typing in long commands, the terminal wouldn't wrap to a newline but would overwrite the current line!

The problem doesn't occur when I remove the Unicode character, and I am pretty sure I escaped everything.

```
export PS1="Δ "
```

[image: The terminal overwriting the current line]

How do I fix this?

Term. Info:

```
$BASH_VERSION => 5.0.16(1)-release
        $TERM => xterm-256color
```

```
! stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel iutf8
```

P.S. the solution at [bash prompt not wrapping as expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239041/bash-prompt-not-wrapping-as-expected) also resulted in odd behavior, due to the fact that ignoring the Unicode character also results in an incorrect character count.

Comment: Does it misbehave even if you remove all the colours and leave only ascii and one Δ in PS1?

Comment: @choroba Yes, even with only one ascii and one unicode, it still overwrites the current line

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Please add info about your bash version (`echo $BASH_VERSION`), the terminal you run this in (`echo $TERM`), and the stty settings (`stty`).

Comment: @mosvy Ok, I have edited the question

Comment: Try setting `LC_ALL= LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` in the shell (no need to export them) and see if it fixes it.

Comment: I got the error `bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)`

Comment: Also, what font does you Terminal use?

Comment: What does the `locale` command say? Try setting it to any utf locale you have available (`locale -a` should give you a list).

Comment: I'm on Parrot OS, and I have posted my `locale` output on pastebin here: [https://pastebin.com/CpDL7dRb](https://pastebin.com/CpDL7dRb)

Comment: My terminal uses the default system font @choroba

Comment: It worked! My locale was set to a non-existing locale, so I changed it to one of the locales in the list `C.UTF-8`, and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As @mosvy said in the comments, the problem was the `locale` setting!

My locale was set to a non-existing locale, so I changed it to one that actually exists, which in my case was `C.UTF-8` (get a list of locales with `locale -a`).

```
export LC_ALL="C.UTF-8"
```